# Get the new value after dragging in jquery gantt chart

Tags: jquery, gantt-chart

I need help saving or atleast printing the values after moving the bars in a gantt chart.

Im using the script 
from here: 
http://lp344.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/.

The thing is it works perfect to slide the bars but i need to get the values when Im releasing them so I can store the changes or whatever.

Got a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PhnYj/3/

and heres the code for the dragging around:

```
$('.ganttRed').draggable({
                    axis: 'x',
                    grid: [24, 24],
                    start: function(event, ui) {
                        $(this).data("startx",$(this).offset().left);
                    },
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        var change = $(this).offset().left - $(this).data("startx");
                        var value = $(this).css('margin-left');
                        value = value.split("px");
                        value = parseInt(value[0]) + change;
                        $(this).css('margin-left', value);
                        $(this).css('left', '');
                    }
                });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: did you have any luck with this?